# Ajax call returns 'error' after 20 seconds

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, timeout

I try to do a call to server. The call response with data which are the result of a database query. 
The query is long (50s). After 20s from the start of call from client the ajax finish on `error` function:

```
$.ajax({
        type : "POST",
        contentType : 'text/plain;charset=UTF-8',
        dataType : 'json',
        data : p_jsonCall,
        url : 'my server....',

        cache : false,
        error : function(p_result) {
            ...
        },
        success : function(p_result) {

...
```

`p_result` is

```
{
    "readyState": 0,
    "responseText": "",
    "status": 0,
    "statusText": "error"
}
```

if I add `timeout : 300000, //5 min` as parameter in ajax call I have the same problem.

p.s. short query (<20s) are managed fine

**p.p.s. I try to run the http call with an external client (Postman) and it runs without errors!**

Comment: unrelated: 50s long query! are you sure? I pity the state of the database server :(

Comment: first check that your request is working fine with a small data

Comment: yes I ave another query that works fine. (if i replace on server the code of the big query with another small query it works)

Comment: did you set timeout on the server side?

Comment: Is requirement to call `error` if response from server > 20s , or _not_ call `error` if response from server > 20s ?

Comment: Since the solution that directly answers your question is easy (increase the timeout), how about you tell us why it takes so long and then we can help improve that instead so you have a more responsive application?

Comment: side note: if this has nothing to do with timeout, you should change the title of your question, it's very confusing, I'll consider that you have configured the server timeout, since you claim that a different client works fine.

Comment: try this `error: function(x, t, m) {
        if(t==="timeout") {
            alert("timed out");
        } else {
            alert(t + ' ' + x.readyState + ' ' + m);
        }
    }`

Comment: I try to run the http call with an external client (Postman) and it runs without errors!

Answer (score 1):

Problem #1: Your server side script should not take ~50s to load. You are doing something wrong with the query.

Problem #2: Even if you set the timeout in jQuery, there might be early timeouts because of other requests. (http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/). So again, fixing it client side is difficult and is not the right way to fix.

Paste a bit of the server side code, and I might be able to help.

Comment: server side script should not take ~50s to load. where is that rule written, then we couldn't change the server timeout and just set it as 50s. again, the OP isn't complaining about the performance here, he just want help with a problem encountered at client side.

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely a server side issue. The server timeouts waiting for the database to finish the query.

Edit:
You could try to use the XMLHttpRequest object directly and see if the issue persists

Comment: I do not think that is a server problem (using an old version of client I have not any errors).

Comment: A server side snippet would be nice in order to test your scenario.

Answer (score 0):

It maybe that your php maximum script time exceeds. Try going manually to that page . If it shows correct then some error is jquery . Else there is some error in Php or serverside.

Btw you should check for it in php.ini . php.net says

> If this is reached, the script returns a fatal error. The default limit is 30 seconds or, if it exists, the max_execution_time value defined in the php.ini.

Try for :

```
set_time_limit(60);
```

Before your script or edit php.ini

Answer (score 0):

You must write

```
 set_time_limit ( 300 );  // time in seconds (5 min.)
```

at top of your ajax file (As you have mentioned in your code `my server....`)
because on server default time out limit is 30 second, you have to increase it too.

you can find more details here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php